# Replace text between two strings in file using linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i have file "acl.txt"

```
 192.168.0.1
 192.168.4.5
 #start_exceptions
 192.168.3.34
 192.168.6.78
 #end_exceptions
 192.168.5.55
```

and another file "exceptions"

```
 192.168.88.88
 192.168.76.6
```

I need to replace everything between #start_exceptions and #end_exceptions with content of exceptions file. I have tried many solutions from this forum but none of them works.

Comment: Why i got -1, what was wrong ?

Comment: I did not down-vote, but I can guess why somebody did: it is useful to show what where your attempts and where you got stuck.

Comment: I am trying to make my own proxy with web filtering and privileges based on ip numbers. Nothing wrong here. But i understand how it looks like.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDITED**:

Ok, if you want to retain the #start and #stop, I will revert to awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN       {p=1}
    /^#start/   {print;system("cat exceptions");p=0}
    /^#end/     {p=1}
    p' acl.txt
```

Thanks to @fedorqui for tweaks in comments below.

Output:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.4.5
#start_exceptions
192.168.88.88
192.168.76.6
#end_exceptions
192.168.5.55
```

p is a flag that says whether or not to print lines. It starts at the beginning as 1, so all lines are printed till I find a line starting with #start. Then I cat the contents of the exceptions file and stop printing lines till I find a line starting with #end, at which point I set the p flag back to 1 so remaining lines get printed.

If you want output to a file, add "> newfile" to the very end of the command like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN       {p=1}
    /^#start/   {print;system("cat exceptions");p=0}
    /^#end/     {p=1}
    p' acl.txt > newfile
```

**YET ANOTHER VERSION IF YOU REALLY WANT TO USE SED**

If you really, really want to do it with sed, you can use nested address spaces, firstly to select the lines between #start_exceptions and #end_exceptions, then again to select the first line within that and also lines other than the #end_exceptions line:

```
sed '
   /^#start/,/^#end/{
      /^#start/{
         n
         r exceptions
      }
      /^#end/!d
   }
' acl.txt
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.4.5
#start_exceptions
192.168.88.88
192.168.76.6
#end_exceptions
192.168.5.55
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I think this will work:

```
sed -e '/^#end/r exceptions' -e '/^#start/,/^#end/d' acl.txt
```

When it finds /^#end/ it reads in the exceptions file. And it also deletes everything between /#start/ and /#end/.

I have left the matching slightly "loose" for clarity of expressing the technique.

Comment: unfortunatelly i want to leave #start_exceptions and #end_exceptions strings.

Comment: why it just prints results on screen but doesnt change file content ?

Comment: Very good one, note that `{if(p!=0)print}` can be reduced to just `p`, as if true, it will perform awk's default action: `{print $0}`. Also your `print $0` in /start/ can be reduced to just `{print}`.

Comment: @fedorqui Many thanks for your suggestions - we are all learning :-) I have incoporated them into my answer so others learn too! +1

Comment: I was once suggested to read [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) and it made a difference! I learnt very much from there and from [the master](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1066031/sudo-o) who suggested it to me :)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of service. Can you accept my answer please so that I get a lovely big green tick :-)

Comment: If my answer worked for you, could you please accept it - by clicking the tick (check mark) near the up and down arrows please?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following, based on [Replace string with contents of a file using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20324/40596):

```
$ sed $'/end/ {r exceptions\n} ; /start/,/end/ {d}' acl.txt
192.168.0.1
192.168.4.5
192.168.88.88
192.168.76.6
192.168.5.55
```

#### Explanation

- `sed $'one_thing; another_thing' ac1.txt` performs the two actions.
- `/end/ {r exceptions\n}` if the line contains `end`, then read the file `exceptions` and append it.
- `/start/,/end/ {d}` from a line containing `start` to a line containing `end`, delete all the lines.

Comment: Not sure why, but that gives this on my machine... sed: 2: "/end/ {r exceptions
} ; ...": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: Mmmm maybe the `$'...'` trick is not performing properly? It worked to me on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.

Comment: Aha! It works under GNU sed for me too, but not on the sed delivered with OSX.

Comment: Nice! I have to say that I am so astonished about the big number of sed versions and things to take into consideration :)

Comment: this works but it doesnt actually make any changes in my acl.txt file. It just prints a result in cmd. One more thing - i dont want to remove #start and #end strings - only text between them

Comment: @Kriss to have in-place substitution, you have to use `-i` flag in `sed`. Also, note that you should update your question showing the desired output, as both of us answering understood that you wanted to replace #start and #end lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with Mark Setchell's solution in MINGW. The caret was not picking up the beginning of line. Indeed, is the detection of the separator dependent on it being at the beginning of the line?
I came up with this awk alternative...

```
$ awk -v data="$(<exceptions)" '
BEGIN {p=1} 
/#start_exceptions/ {print; print data;p=0}
/#end_exceptions/ {p=1}
p
' acl.txt
```