# Replace each nth occurs from anything between two strings using nth line from another file

Tags: string, file, awk, replace, gsub

I would actually like to replace anything that is between two strings, `group_tree (` and `)\t",` on the `0.txt` file every *nth* occurrence using the *nth* line from another file `1.txt` through `awk`.

This would be something like [Replace each nth occurrence of 'foo' by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738909/replace-each-nth-occurrence-of-foo-by-numerically-respective-nth-line-of-a-sup)

I've been looking for something, I tried to adapt this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21876700/10824251, but I have no idea how it works for what I look for. Here my attempts:

```
awk \

'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /^group_tree(/ /{gsub("tortoise", a[++i])} /^)\t",/1' \
    1.txt 0.txt
```

Do not generate any result just the message:

```
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:      GNU long options: (standard)
.....
```

My sources files:

**0.txt:**

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
```

**1.txt:**

```
(food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,)
(sky, cat,)(sun, sea,)
(car, shape)(milk, market,)
(man, shirt)(hair, life)
(dog, big)(bal, pink)
```

My desired output `2.txt`:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
```

Comment: Are those `\t`s in your input literally the 2 chars ```\``` and `t` or is there actually a literal tab char in your input?

Comment: In your question text you say `group_tree (` with a space but in your sample input/output there is no such space. Please [edit] your question to make both the text and the example consistent and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX awk:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {a[i++] = $0}
FNR!=NR {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,
             "group_tree("a[j%i]")\\t\"")) {j++}
         print}' 1.txt 0.txt
```

Your description has a space between `group_tree` and `(`, but your example data does not. I allowed for either case.

This is not completely robust, due to greedy `.*` between the two patterns. Probably okay if all your data is similar to the example.

Note that `sub(/foo/, a[j++])` iterates `j` whether `sub` succeeds or not.

Comment: I am resuming the works of this question now, I did not notice the space you mentioned but I will try to correct this, for now your response worked and I see how she works.

Comment: That would fail if `1.txt` contained a `&`. Try changing `sun, sea` to `sun & sea` in `1.txt`.

Comment: @dan could explain the meaning of `j%i`, I know it is a remaing, but I'm not sure if `j` and `i` are indices.

Comment: @dan could give me an idea of how `gsub` could also replace `sub`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting from your call to awk is because you have a blank line between `awk \` and the script so it's like calling awk with no script and no arguments. If you change it from this:

```
awk \

'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /^group_tree(/ /{gsub("tortoise", a[++i])} /^)\t",/1' \
    1.txt 0.txt
```

to this:

```
awk \
'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /^group_tree(/ /{gsub("tortoise", a[++i])} /^)\t",/1' \
    1.txt 0.txt
```

or more idiomatically this:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /^group_tree(/ /{gsub("tortoise", a[++i])} /^)\t",/1
' 1.txt 0.txt
```

then you won't get that error message any longer (but you will get a different error message as the script still contains syntax errors).

To solve your actual problem, though, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `ARGIND`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
ARGIND == 1 {
    newVals[++totNew] = $0
    next
}
match($0,/(.*group_tree\().*(\)\\t",.*)/,a) {
    newIdx = ( (++numNew - 1) % totNew ) + 1
    $0 = a[1] newVals[newIdx] a[2]
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk 1.txt 0.txt
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
```

The above assumes there's only one `)\t",` after each `group_tree(`.

Comment: you could explain every step of your script, the execution simply shows no error and file 2.txt gets the content of 0.txt

Comment: What part of it isn't clear? I think the structure of what it's doing is obvious and I gave it extremely clear variable names so you know what each of them is being used for so I can't imagine what would need explanation.

Comment: The test of the other response was faster because it already worked on the first attempt and other tests by changing the two strings. I'll test your update and give you feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: The main differences between my solution and the currently accepted answer are that I use capture groups so I don't need to specify the same delimiter strings twice, once in the regexp and then again in the replacement, and I'm doing a literal string replacement instead of a backreference-enabled replacement with *sub() so it'll work no matter which characters 1.txt contains, e.g. `&`. I'm also testing `ARGIND==1` instead of using `NR==FNR` so you can just duplicate that for any additional files (which I know you'll be adding in followup questions). My script is gawk-only though.

Comment: Your code using `FNR` was not necessary, I just used `tortoise` in an attempt of my code in my question but it has no complete meaning for me. About your last update in tst.awk, it worked correctly, but I'm still trying to understand everything he does, maybe this takes time.

Comment: What code using `FNR`? I don't know what `tortoise` is or how it's related to my answer. If you tell me what part of my answer you don't understand I'll explain it.